# Styled-Components mobile menu

Tags: css, styled-components

I'm trying to achieve the following result. I have a responsive menu, however when the screen is less than 768px should hide a few elements (the ItemsMenu and LanguageItems) from the horizontal menu that it is for the desktop and display in the burger menu for mobile.

I'm having an issue because if I use display: none; it'll hide in both displays, for desktop and for mobile. How would be a better approach to achieve this result:

**Component:**

```
function Languages() {
  const [language, setLanguage] = useState("en");

  const handleLanguage = (language) => (event) => {
    setLanguage(language);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Lang>
        <Logo>
          <h1>Flávio</h1>
        </Logo>
        <ItemsMenu>
          <li>{languages[language].about}</li>
          <li>{languages[language].project}</li>
          <li>{languages[language].contact}</li>
        </ItemsMenu>
        <LanguageIcon>
          <img src={English} alt="EN" onClick={handleLanguage("en")} />
          <img src={Japanese} alt="JP" onClick={handleLanguage("jp")} />
          <img src={Russian} alt="RU" onClick={handleLanguage("ru")} />
          <img src={Portuguese} alt="PT-BR" onClick={handleLanguage("ptbr")} />
        </LanguageIcon>
      </Lang>
    </>
  );
}
```

**Styled-component:**

```
import styled from "styled-components";

export const Lang = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;

  li:hover {
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
`;

export const Logo = styled.div`
  color: #2e186a;
  cursor: pointer;
`;

export const ItemsMenu = styled.ul`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #2e186a;
  margin: auto;

  li {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #2e186a;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-left: 1.5rem;
  }

  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    /* display: none; */
  }
`;

export const LanguageIcon = styled.div`
  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    /* display: none; */
  }

  img {
    height: 2em;
    margin-left: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  img:hover {
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
`;
```

Comment: css cannot make a distinction between a desktop or mobile device, it can only check a certain screen height or width. 
Are you sure you want a desktop with screen width smaller then 768px to show the element and a mobile device with screen width smaller then 768px to hide the element?

Comment: 768px it is for responsiveness only. It is for use in the mobile.